# FirebaseAnalytics is missing several parameter constants

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

I would like to pass along an array of bundles to FirebaseAnalytics as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param#public-static-final-string-items) but FirebaseAnalytics.Param does not contain an ITEMS value. In fact, it only seems to contain a subset of the [values it should contain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param) as shown here:
[image: available item param constants]

I have firebaseanalytics version 17.4.4 and I tried to fill in the Param.ITEMS constant value myself ("items" according to the docs) but DebugView shows a firebase error (20 - Event array parameter name is invalid). All other events and parameters seem to work just fine according to DebugView and I found nobody with similar problems. Does anyone have any ideas as to why I only see a subset of the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you perform a Gradle sync, as `FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEMS` is definitely available in v17.4.4.

Here it is in my project, note the version number in the bottom right:
[image: firebase 17.4.4 param items]

If you're still having trouble, mouseover one of the options in your dropdown and it should show you the version being used.

Comment: I use gradle sync quite a lot but the tip about the version was very useful! In my case mouseover didn't do it for me and I had to click on the bottom right three dots to select Quick Documentation. It showed me I was using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.1.0` even though I had everything setup like the docs stated. Turns out I still had `firebase-core` in my project which had a fixed dependency on 17.1.0 . `firebase-core` is no longer needed and after removing it everything worked!